# Why does fastlanes increment_build_number not find my project?

Tags: fastlane

I've moved my fastlane folder out of the xcode directory, so I'm trying to get it to target it. I have this is my Fastfile:

```
increment_build_number(
  xcodeproj: "../ember-cordova/cordova/platforms/ios/Patontheback.xcodeproj",
  build_number: ENV['CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM']
)
```

Which gives

```
[06:50:47]: ------------------------------------
[06:50:47]: --- Step: increment_build_number ---
[06:50:47]: ------------------------------------
[06:50:47]: Error setting value '../ember-cordova/cordova/platforms/ios/Patontheback.xcodeproj' for option 'xcodeproj'
[06:50:47]: You passed invalid parameters to 'increment_build_number'.
[06:50:47]: Check out the error below and available options by running `fastlane action increment_build_number`
[06:50:47]: Variable Dump:
[06:50:47]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios beta", :SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE=>"app-store"}
[06:50:47]: Could not find Xcode project
```

xcodeproj definitely exists in that location:

```
$ ls -l ../ember-cordova/cordova/platforms/ios/Patontheback.xcodeproj
total 28
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kitsunde staff 25639 Sep 23 02:57 project.pbxproj
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it appends `../` to the path. So it's relative the parent directory and not the directory of the Fastlane file.